# Python regex combine two lines into one

Tags: python, regex

I'm scraping info from a webpage and I'm trying to combine two lines of output into one line.  I've been trying to do this through regex patterns, though I'm not sure if it's possible to do it that way, or if there's a better way. The original output is:

```
Season Dates: Nov 21
2014 to Apr 19
```

along with other lines above and below, which I would like to keep as separate lines.

I would like to return for these two lines:

```
Season Dates: Nov 21 2014 to Apr 19
```

I've tried:

```
result2 = re.sub("(Season\sDates:\s[JFMAJASOND][aepuoc][nbrpylgcv]\s[0-9]?[0-9])", '\12[0-9][0-9][0-9]\sto\s[JFMAJASOND][aepuoc][nbrpylgcv]\s[0-9]?[0-9]', result)
```

The output I get from this is:

```
[0-9][0-9][0-9]\sto\s[JFMAJASOND][aepuoc][nbrpylgcv]\s[0-9]?[0-9]
```

I've tried multiple other variations including assigning the regex to variables, etc, but can't get anything to work.

From what I can find online, I'm not sure that the replacement value can be a regex pattern, but I'm still unclear on that. Is this possible through regex, or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: *Two lines of outputs*..?..From where these outputs?...

Comment: They are from a web scrape.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
r=re.compile('(Season\sDates):\s(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dev)\s(\d+)\s*$\s*(\d+)\s+to\s+(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dev)\s+(\d+)',re.MULTILINE)
p="""Season Dates: Nov 21
2014 to Apr 19"""
r.sub('\g<1>: \g<2> \g<3> \g<4> to \g<5> \g<6>',p)
```

You can capture the `:` and the `to` or combine some of the groups together if you want. Let me know if you need more or something different.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a try.  Will this account for changing content from the web scrape? If for example the Apr 19 changed to Apr 20, would it still work?

Comment: Yes,  I'm matching dates with \d+ (one or more numbers).

Comment: Ah, I was looking at the code wrong, but got it now, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
re.sub(r"\n"," ",test_str)
```

If its such a simple use case you can simply do this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/fX3oF6/1

EDIT:

if more than 2 lines are there use

```
 (\bSeason\s+Dates:\s*\S+\s+\d+)\n(\d+\s+to\s+\S+\s+\d+)
```

Replace by `\1 \2`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/fX3oF6/7

Comment: This would work if it was just two lines, but there are multiple other lines above and below that I would like to keep as different rows.  If I used that the whole thing would become one line.